# Qt Parent child relationship for independent qmainwindows

Tags: qt, window, parent-child

Using Pyside, but a general Qt question:

I am building a Qt app with a controlling QMainWindow.  From this window the user can open other QMainWindows (or QDialogs) and from some of those she can open more.  The user is intended to think of the first QMainWindow as "the app" and the others as lots of different views on more or less the same data.

So I'd like all the windows to be independently stackable so the user can set up the screen to their own requirements. In particular I want the user to be able to bring the first QMainWindow on top if wanted.  But I don't really want each window to have its own task bar entry (though I can live with that). Also I would like them to minimise and restore together, and I would like them all to close when the first main window closes.

If I parent them all on the first mainwindow it works nicely except they stay on top of it which is not what I want.

Instead I have it kind of working by making them all independent with parent = None.  Then I register them all with the main window and close them all when it closes.  But this makes them a bit too independent - they minimise separately and have their own task bar entry.

Am I missing some obvious fix to this?  Is there any easy way (a flag?) to stop the children staying on top of the parent?

Or is there some UI guideline that I am breaking by desiring this?

Or is there a cleaner design somehow?  I thought of adding a dummy parent that they could all descend from but maybe that's messy. Would that parent need a visual presence?  I wouldn't want that.

Suggestions?

Comment: Isn't tabbing inside one single QMainWindow a better UI design? (I just want to give you an alternative idea.)

Comment: Thanks - that's the sort of idea I'm looking for.  But it's not right for me because the users need to look at several windows at once: for example, they get maps at different zooms and also tables all to look at together...

Comment: Ok, what about this compromise: Tabs inside the main window + the option to "open tab in external window". This window could then be a simple QWidget without menu and status bar. So the user knows that this is an external view. There wouldn't bee that much confusion like "What again was the app's main window?" Because that would be the problem if all of your main windows look like the same but one of them is *the real main one*. (Again, just an idea.)

Comment: I might try that.  Though I will still have the same problem if the QWidget  (I would use QDialog, I guess) insists on being on top of the MainWindow.

Comment: On second thoughts - this might be OK.  The QMainWindow could have even its own contents as a tab.  So, once dragged out, all the tabs would be required only to be on top of the empty tab frame, which would be OK.  I'll give this a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I thought I would add what I eventually settled upon.  This was particularly inspired by the comments of @leemes (Thanks - good stuff) and a little experimentation of my own.

I used the code attached here [DetachTabExample](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/50024-Drag-n-drop-Tab-inside-and-outside-the-Main-Application?p=225235#post225235%7CThread)
to develop a "Detachable Tab" widget and tab bar. This allows tabs to be dragged outside the main window when they become independent windows.  Then if closed they return to the tab bar.

Then I placed all my content in the `QMainWindow` but in separate tabs. The users can drag the ones they want out on to the other monitor.  Seems to be working fine.  There are still some extra windows that I have floating but it has cut down the clutter and clarified the structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many QMainWindows as you want, or parentless QWidgets. I think the best way to handle your situation is to create your own pseudo parent-child relationship like this:

In your QMainWindow subclass, store a QList of all the QWidgets you want it to manage. Then, again in your QMainWindow subclass, reimplement methods such as `QWidget::closeEvent()`, `QWidget::hideEvent()` (for when the window is minimized), and `QWidget::showEvent()` (for when it is restored) so that it also closes, hides, or shows all of the widgets in its QList. Make sure to also `delete` them in the QMainWindow subclass's destructor. Now, whenever you create a sub-window, pass the main window a pointer to it **not as a normal QWidget child**, but just so that it can be added to the main window's QList of QWidgets to manage. E.g.:

```
MainWindowSubclass::addPseudoChild(QWidget *pseudoChild)
{
    myListOfPseudoChildren.append(pseudoChild);
}
```

Another alternative that hasn't been mentioned yet is populating a [QMdiArea](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmdiarea.html) with [QMdiSubWindows](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmdisubwindow.html). It doesn't do exactly what you asked for, but it's a pretty clean design nonetheless.

Comment: OK thanks.  That is more or less what I have done, thought I hadn't connected the hide and show events.  Actually, I hadn't done the delete.  Some of the windows WA_DeleteOnClose (and remove themselves from their pseudo-parent when they close).  Others just close (and may be reused), and don't delete until the whole app closes.  I figured I don't need to delete those ones.

Comment: Thanks also for the MDI suggestion. But I don't think that fits in this case.  An important use case is to keep one window up, say on a separate monitor, and then work on the others.  I think it's easiest if I give the users maximum flexibility about placing and sizing the windows.